# Prove by contrapositive: Φ∪{β} ⊨ α & Φ∪{¬β} ⊨ α iff Φ ⊨ α

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

We are to prove this by contrapositive (by the way: Φ is a set of formulas of predicate logic and α a formula of predicate logic)

I've managed the Right to Left proof, but I struggle with the Left to Right direction.

Presumably, what I want is that by assuming Φ ⊭ α, then it is not the case that Φ∪{β} ⊨ α & Φ∪{¬β} ⊨ α - i.e. that either Φ∪{β} ⊭ α or Φ∪{¬β} ⊭ α

This is what I've done so far:

> Assume Φ ⊭ α.
>
> Then there is at least one interpretations U such that ⊨*(U)* Φ but ⊭*(U)* α.
>
> We also know the Law of Excluded Middle holds for all interpretations. So, for all interpretations U', ⊨*(U’) (β v ¬β) ⇒ ⊨*(U’) β or  ⊨_(U’)¬β.
>
> This also holds for Φ∪{β}: for all interpretations U', either ⊨*(U’) Φ∪{β} or ⊨*(U’) Φ∪{¬β} ⇒ either ⊨*(U’) Φ∪{β} or ⊭*(U’) Φ∪{β}.

And that's basically it, so far.

I do not know how to proceed with a proof that shows that if Φ∪{β} ⊨ α, then Φ∪{¬β} ⊭ α *and* if Φ∪{¬β} ⊨ α, then Φ∪{β} ⊭ α. Which I think is what I need.

Though, as I'm writing this I think this may be on the right lines:

1) If Φ∪{¬β} ⊨ α, then for all interpretations U such that ⊨*(U) Φ∪{¬β}, ⊨*(U) α.

Need to prove there is at least one interpretations U', such that ⊨*(U) Φ∪{β} and  ⊭*(U) α.

Maybe: since Φ∪{¬β} and Φ∪{β} are contradictory, then if ⊨*(U) Φ∪{¬β}, ⊨*(U) α, then if ⊨*(U) Φ∪{β}, then  ⊭*(U) α. (a lot of ifs and thens here ...). My rational here is roughly that if all interpretations that have ⊨*(U) Φ∪{¬β} also have ⊨*(U) α, then all the interpretations that have ⊨*(U) Φ∪{β} will also have ⊭*(U) α

2) If Φ∪{β} ⊨ α, then for all interpretations U such that ⊨*(U) Φ∪{β}, ⊨*(U) α. 
Need to prove there is at least one interpretations U', such that ⊨*(U) Φ∪{¬β} and  ⊭*(U) α. 
Maybe: the opposite of what I said above.

Is this anywhere near correct? If not, how should one proceede with such a proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there is an interpretation $U$ that models $\Phi$ and where $\alpha$ is false and check $\beta$.

- If $\beta$ is true in $U$, then $\Phi\cup\{\beta\}\not\models\alpha$.
- If $\beta$ is false in $U$, then $\Phi\cup\{\lnot\beta\}\not\models\alpha$.

Conversely, suppose that either $\Phi\cup\{\beta\}\not\models\alpha$ or $\Phi\cup\{\lnot\beta\}\not\models\alpha$. In either case, $\Phi\not\models\alpha$.